# What could be the cause when the HTML and PHP code already finish execute but page still loading?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've created a HTML + PHP simple page with some javascript that provide from google like adsense and google plus button.

The thing is the page is very short. I meant like not much content on it and I'm curious that why when the page is fully loaded like everything appeared and nothing missing, but the bar on google chrome or like firefox is still loading?

I did test removed the javascript for ads and button and it still having the samething

Is this normal? or maybe something wrong in my code that I should look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/

It will let you know what is still loading.

If nothing pops out then your JavaScript is probably in an infinite loop.

Comment: This is a great website I never know of. I will defiantly check this out!

Answer (score 2):

Open the developers tools (Ctrl-Shift-I in Chrome), go to the network tab and load your page, you'll see exactly what component is taking what time.

Most clever add-ons / plugins like google+, Analytics, etc. load when your own content is completely loaded so you might see some action after the page is visually done.

**Edit:** The developers tools in Chrome can easily be reached from the menu as well...

Comment: @iambriansreed The OP states he's using Chrome, so that's the easiest way to go without me having to ask if firebug is installed...